# DynamoDB C# expression to query/scan

Tags: c#, linq, amazon-web-services, lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have a generic repository structure in place using interfaces and I am trying to develop a DynamoDB implementation for this. This is my first experience with DynamoDB and NoSQL (previously all T-SQL).

The problem I am having is that I am unable to find any way of converting a lambda expression in C# to a format that I can use to query/scan DynamoDB.

My Get method looks like this:

```
public Task<TEntity> GetAsync(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> where)
{
    return await this.DataContext.ScanAsync(...);
}
```

Is there an existing way to do this? There doesn't seem to be anything in the documentation that addresses this and I am struggling to find an example of where someone else has had a similar problem.

Maybe my lack of experience with NoSQL and/or DynamoDB is just the problem here. If so, please do point out a better approach if necessary though I will note that as previously mentioned, I am implementing an interface which is already defined and changing this isn't really an option.

Comment: Are you looking for [this](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=linq2dynamodb)?

Comment: That looks like it might be helpful but I don't seem to be able to find any examples of how you actually use it!

Comment: You should be able to find some samples on guthub, to which the code has migrated, or in the posts mentioned [here](https://github.com/scale-tone/linq2dynamodb/blob/master/README.md).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can use the [ServiceStack.Aws](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Aws), which is similar to LINQ.
For example:

```
using System;
using Amazon;
using Amazon.DynamoDBv2;
using ServiceStack;
using ServiceStack.Text;
using ServiceStack.Aws.DynamoDb;
using ServiceStack.DataAnnotations;

var awsDb = new AmazonDynamoDBClient("keyId","key",
    new AmazonDynamoDBConfig { ServiceURL="http://localhost:8000"});
var db = new PocoDynamo(awsDb);

public class Todo
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }
    public bool Done { get; set; }
}

db.RegisterTable<Todo>();

db.DeleteTable<Todo>();  // Delete existing Todo Table (if any)
db.InitSchema();         // Creates Todo DynamoDB Table

var newTodo = new Todo {
    Content = "Learn PocoDynamo",
    Order = 1
};
db.PutItem(newTodo);

var savedTodo = db.GetItem<Todo>(newTodo.Id);
"Saved Todo: {0}".Print(savedTodo.Dump());

savedTodo.Done = true;
db.PutItem(savedTodo);

var updatedTodo = db.GetItem<Todo>(newTodo.Id);
"Updated Todo: {0}".Print(updatedTodo.Dump());

db.DeleteItem<Todo>(newTodo.Id);

var remainingTodos = db.GetAll<Todo>();
"No more Todos: {0}".Print(remainingTodos.Dump());
```